# A difficulty in understanding multivariable Fermat theorem proof.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The theorem and its proof is given below :

> [image]

But I do not understand :

1- why clearly "$F$ is differentiable in this interval"?

2- why $F$ attains its extreme value at $x=a$?

3- why $F^{'}(a_{1}) = 0 $ is the same as $f_{x_{1}}^{'}(a) = 0$?

Could anyone explain this points for me please?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but how is this multivariable calculus? $f$ seems to be a function of a single variable.

Comment: I am sorry I put the wrong picture @NeilA. I will edit my question....thank you.

Comment: @NeilA. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

1. If $f$ is differentiable at that point, then it has some partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ which is the same as the derivative of $F$
2. Since $f$ achieves it's extremum at $a$ and $F$ is the value of $f$ along the direction of the first component, $F$ must also achieve it's extremum there. (Imagine tracing a 2d plot out of a surface plot)
3. The partial of $f$ takes it's derivative in that direction while holding all other variables constant. $F'$ is $f$ with all but that variable held constant, so it's derivative must be the same as the partial